# Attempting to create partition in parted gives Error: Can't have the end before the start!

Tags: partitioning, parted

This is a server without a GUI and I need to create a partition with the command line.

Here is the output of `fdisk` to show the disk structure:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 447.13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZ7LM480
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6E79FEC6-5E0A-5D44-B6E6-EEA7E252FFA3

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd7  201328640 243271679  41943040   20G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdd8  243271680 285214719  41943040   20G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdd10 327157760 369100799  41943040   20G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdd11 369100800 411043839  41943040   20G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdd12 411043840 935331839 524288000  250G Linux filesystem
```

I want to create partition exactly in the space between `/dev/sdd8` and `/dev/sdd10`

I'm trying the following command:

```
parted /dev/sdd -- mkpart primary ext3 285214720s 41943040s
```

But I receive an error:

```
Error: Can't have the end before the start! (start sector=285214720 length=-243271679)
```

Why am I getting an error? What is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last number needs to be the final sector from the start of the device, not the number of sectors to use:

```
parted /dev/sdd -- mkpart primary ext3 285214720 327157759
```

As an aside, it may make sense to begin transitioning to `ext4`, as `ext3` has long since been superseded

Comment: parted /dev/sdd -- mkpart primary ext4 285214720s 327157759s